# data is not bulk importing properly in to MySQL database

Tags: c#, mysql

I have used MySqlBulkLoader Class to import csv data to MYSQL database.But all the data which retrieved are null (except 1 column) for some reason. The source code is as follows.

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using MySql.Data;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            string connStr = "server=localhost;user=root;database=database;port=3306;password=123";
            MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connStr);

            MySqlBulkLoader bl = new MySqlBulkLoader(conn);
            bl.TableName = "jobs";
            bl.FieldTerminator = "\t";
            bl.LineTerminator = "\n";
            bl.FileName = @"C:\Users\source\repos\WindowsService1\WindowsService1\bin\Debug\data.csv";
            bl.FileName = bl.FileName.Replace(@"\\", @"\ \");
            bl.NumberOfLinesToSkip = 3;

            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Connecting to MySQL...");
                conn.Open();

                // Upload data from file
                int count = bl.Load();
                Console.WriteLine(count + " lines uploaded.");





                conn.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Done.");
        }
    }
}
```

There are 3 columns in the csv file so does the database table. I double checked the names of those locations. There is no issue with those. Anyone who could catch this logical error will get a free cofee for sure. #savemylife

Question update: The basic structureof the csv file is as follows.[image]

And the MySQL database structure: [image]

CSV file structure in a notepad looks like this.

```
nJobNumber,strClientReference,datPromisedDelivery
5754,in progress,22/02/2018 11:30:00 AM
6524,cancelled,13/03/2018 5:00:00 PM
```

Comment: Can you share a sample file and the structure of the database table?  Are the columns values separated by tabs?

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/show-create-table.html shows you how to get the CREATE TABLE.

Comment: What happens if you put quotes around `in progress` and `cancelled`?

Comment: hey I just tried it. Nothing happens. all the data write to the database are null.@mjwills

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your file is a CSV file (fields separated by commas). But in your code, you are saying they are separated by tabs.

```
 bl.FieldTerminator = "\t";
```

Need to be changed to

```
bl.FieldTerminator = ",";
```

Another issue is the following line

```
bl.NumberOfLinesToSkip = 3;
```

However your example file has only one header line, so it probably should be

```
bl.NumberOfLinesToSkip = 1;
```

Comment: Yeah I tried that too beforehand. It's not working either. @Dijkgraaf

Comment: @RyanOscar  I've added some details about the Lines To Skip.  Is that the issue?

Comment: @ Dijkgraaf Actually the issue was the database data types. By workbench it automatically set the date column as date/time and when I change that to varchar it's all good. That's why the values were null. Thanks for your assistance though. Appreciate that!